# Software that simulates a wooden drawing doll?

Tags: software-recommendation, drawing

I am learning to draw figures, and a wooden doll (pictured below) is a lot of help. But I'm having issues keeping a specific angle in regards to the doll. Even a little shift in position can make the drawing off.

[image: doll]

**Is there a program that provides a 3D dummy figure which can be adjusted to any position like a wooden doll?** This would enable me to keep the angle exactly the same without having to worry about movement.

Comment: As an alternative, take a photo after posing it.

Comment: Hi @Doomista, I took the liberty of editing your question so it's a bit clearer and structured. If you think there's something wrong with my edit, you can always [edit] it back. Enjoy the site!

Comment: Similar question: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16276/how-to-study-anatomy-as-an-artist

Answer (score 6):

In the realm of "Free" alternatives, two pop into my mind that I use:

### [Blender](https://www.blender.org/)

A free 3d Rendering engine which Offers a variety of rendering and animation options for creating photos and movies.

EDIT: Since the original request was for the wooden mannequin, here's that exact model already done for you in blender for free: [Wooden Mannequin - Rigged](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/74733) by jgilhutton.  (The actual model doesn't come with the chair, that's an additional 3dmodel)

[image]

### [Daz3d](http://www.daz3d.com/)

A free 3d rendering engine similar to Poser, but with a "premium" shop where you purchase models.

For either of these options, you should key in on the words "**[rigging](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Animation/BSoD/Character_Animation/Rigging)**", "rigged" or "fully rigged" models.  Those models have all of the joints to act like the puppet, where you can move the joints and the model acts like it has a connected **[skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation)** that can be animated.

Comment: I vote up for Daz3D. Blender does not have a built in pupet to manipulate, so i do not think is the best recomendation alone. But it can be complemented with makehuman http://www.makehuman.org/

Answer (score 5):

All 3D apps that I have used could do this. Most modern posing apps have have a much more elaborate model than that but many can also use a a classic wooden mannequin.

But perhaps of special interest is [Poser 3D](http://my.smithmicro.com/poser-3d-animation-software.html). Poser was originally meant for this purpose only (tough years of adding features means that's no longer just the case) there is a number of alternatives such as [Design Doll](http://terawell.net/terawell/) which is free and pretty good.

But yes you could use any 3d app like Maya, 3ds MAX, Blender or sketchup. Models are pretty easy to find and skin. In less than 10 minutes of googling i found  20 or so different model files. And it takes about 20 minutes to make one (and making your own software is also not that hard good game dev starter project in fact)

Comment: Only you would answer this by suggest making your own software! :p

Answer (score 5):

My 2 cents.

Besides the already mentioned, Daz3D, Poser and Design Doll there are 3 more I know:

Makehuman: http://www.makehumancommunity.org/ which can be used in conjunction with Blender.

Anotherone that works inside blender is MB-lab https://mb-lab-community.github.io/MB-Lab.github.io/

and IClone http://www.reallusion.com/iclone/default.html

I use a lot Daz3D. It is free and a solid program. So that would be my first choice.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Design Doll http://terawell.net/terawell/, it's free and the web site hasn't cause any problems for me yet. You are able to move the figure in whatever way you want, you can move any joint and it's a great thing for reference. Everything is very realistic and fun to use.

Comment: Can you please include a link and possibly also a screenshot, just to make your answer more informative.

Answer (score 0):

I think http://justsketch.me is exactly what you're looking for. It has free posable mannequins (they used to have a wood one too).