# Fastest way to learn anatomy and proportions?

Tags: illustration, anatomy-for-artists

I'm trying to improve my drawings and 3D sculptures by learning proper anatomy and proportions, but I just can't seem to find any teachers whose method of teaching works for me. In addition, I'm very impatient so I keep getting frustrated quickly and then taking longer than I should to learn what I need. What's the best and fastest way to learn anatomy? I know it takes a lot of practice, but where I should I look for lessons? Preferably somewhere free as I'm a poor college student.

Comment: Related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16276/how-to-study-anatomy-as-an-artist