# I want to learn anatomy without looking at nude pictures

Tags: anatomy-for-artists

I really want to learn and find books about anatomy, but I don't know any book that teaches it without forcing me to look at naked photos. I don't mind muscles but I do NOT want to draw uncomfortable places.

Comment: Unless your squee limit is *very* low, there are lots of other human parts you can draw anatomically correct. Just leave the offensive parts blank, or for bonus points, cover them with an arm, knee, or a conveniently draped piece of clothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to study anatomy as an artist?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16276/how-to-study-anatomy-as-an-artist)

Comment: No, this is a special case: "How do I study anatomy without risk of seeing private parts?".

Comment: Just draw people with clothes on. However you won't be an effective artist if you don't understand how all parts of the body work and sit on a frame.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor to be honestyou do not lose much if you draw people in swimwear, or underwear. Very rarely do you need to see things drop differently than that to draw them clothed

Comment: I really know where you are coming from! I am studying Anatomy too, and it felt uncomfortable looking at all the nude pictures. But, you will get used to it. :) Good luck!

Answer (score 11):

How can I learn to cook without tasting??

I understand perhaps some apprehension if you see nudity as always sexual, however the human form isn't meant to be sexual in all cases. Study of anatomy is one such case.

You *could* focus on muscular anatomy, that would prevent the showing of the dermis and recognizable "parts".

Things like:

- http://www.innerbody.com/anatomy/muscular/upper-torso

or

- https://www.getbodysmart.com/muscular-system

Then it would be merely up to you to define where the dermis actually falls.

Comment: We had that 19th (?) century photos book at school, the one with naked dudes doing all kinds of gymnastics in glorious black and white photo strips. It felt odd having to study that in detail – until I realised I was *probably* concentrating on the wrong thing. Things got better then. Not my drawing skills, unfortunately.

Comment: To be fair Mozart did alright deaf. Most of us are unfortunately  no Mozart's..

Comment: Well Mozart had vibration... I suppose if you *felt* the human form you could avoid looking at it. :)

Comment: This is a cultural thing i suppose. There are cultures where nudity is not a big deal. I mean i have seen most of my friends nude in sauna, and also half that number of their wives too.

Comment: @Ryan Mozart was not deaf. You must be thinking of Beethoven.

Comment: Err.. I typed Beethoven.. yeah I did.. don't know why this site changed it to Mozart :)

Answer (score 2):

You can practice drawing people in public or ask your friends. Plenty of figure drawing classes use clothed models.  Anatomy books, photographs and sculpture are good references. It is useful practice to sketch the figures you find in these places.

With Safe Search on you can search google images for "human figure" "muscle structure" "anatomy" "life drawing" etc. You may get guts and bodies but not nudity.

Comment: clothed models like fashion models ? thanks anyways!

Comment: No just figure models. I took a class where we had lots of "regular" body types, elderly, different weights and textures, it was great. Really all you need is people to draw and pictures work great.

Answer (score 2):

A few figure study/anatomy study websites have a "clothed" option. It is fairly easy to practice anatomy even when clothes are on, buy the bridgeman anatomy book too, most of it focus on the muscular part of the body, i'll leave some links for you:
[Figure drawing website, make sure to tick the decent models thingie](https://line-of-action.com/practice-tools/figure-drawing/)
[One of the bridgeman books that helped me the most](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486211045)